# MySql : What is the best way to delete a lot of datasets in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I have an application running in php which creates a huge amount of data. From time to time it is necessary to move some of the data to an archive table and continue with just the recent data e.g. the data of the last month.

What would be the best approach to achieve this while the application continues to run on this database. We talk about up to 30Gb of Data in one table.

What I tried now, but I was not satisfied was this:
In a php script I created a second table and with a loop I transferred the data I want to archive to the new table. Now we have nearly 2x 30Gb of data. With a second script I delete now the obsolete data from the first table in chunks by 10 000 datasets in the hope I don't overload the database and the replication to the two slave databases.

Is this the best way to do it or has anyone an better approach?

Comment: Have you considered [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/partitioning.html), perhaps by month?

Comment: Not yet. That sounds very promising!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PARTITIONing is the best way to DELETE old data.  However, to "move" the data to an archive, you need a new enough version (5.6.8) to have "transportable tablespaces"; that will be even faster.

Here is a general discussion of techniques for DELETEing large number of rows; it can be adapted to also INSERT into another table:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Here is code to assist in the monthly (or weekly) purging of data from a partitioned table:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint  It gives hints on how to best lay out the partitions for a "time series" like you seem to have.

Transportable tablespaces require that you first PARTITION the table.  Then...:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-copying.html  and  http://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/09/mysql-5-6-transportable-tablespaces-best-practices/